# blazor - onvalidsubmit shows error message but triggers onvalidsubmitcode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying a small app with blazor.  The code has a class and edit form. The edit form shows the errors on invalid data, but still runs the submit code.

I am only testing 2 fields in the form for now to learn.

**Class Data Annotations:**

```
 public class DBPersonDetails
    {

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Client ID")]
        public UInt16 Client_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Branch ID")]
        public UInt16 Branch_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Person ID")]
        public UInt32 Person_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Person Title")]
        public string PersonTitle { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Person Type ID")]
        public Lookup_Person_Type Person_Type_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Person Gender ID")]
        public Lookup_Person_Gender Person_Gender_ID { get; set; }

        
        [StringLength(100)]
        [EmailAddress]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]        
        [Display(Name = "Person Email")]
        public string? Person_Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        [Display(Name = "Person Mobile")]
        public string? Person_Mobile { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Person Dob")]
        public DateTime? Person_Dob { get; set; }

    }

public class DBPeople
{
    public DBPersonDetails dbPersonDetails { get; set; } = new DBPersonDetails();

    public DBPersonAddress dbPersonAddress { get; set; } = new DBPersonAddress();

    public DBPersonProofs DBPersonProofs { get; set; } = new DBPersonProofs();

}
```

**Blazor Page Code:**

```
@page "/person"

<h3>Person</h3>

<h3>contact Add Page</h3>

<EditForm Model="@person" OnValidSubmit="@onvalidsubmitcode" >
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="person.dbPersonDetails.PersonTitle" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="person.dbPersonDetails.Person_Email" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn-dark">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
    

@code {

    //public Models.Person person { get; set; } = new Models.Person();

    public Data.People.DBPeople person { get; set; } = new Data.People.DBPeople();

    private void onvalidsubmitcode()
    {
        
        var k = person;

    }

}
```

I checked with breakpoints on `onvalidsubmitcode` but it is getting triggered even when the data is not valid.

Example of data entered:
[image]

Although the validation error is displayed the code still hits submit code.  Please help me on what error I have done or what I have missed/messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit context is person. The inputs are bound to dbPersonDetails.
'person' is of type DbPeople and is passing validation. You need to set the
Model parameter to an instance of DBPersonDetails

Comment: yes, person is the object/property for the page.  So that is correct to my knowledge.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Model="@person.dbPersonDetails"

Comment: In the inside bindings at input tag level, I have given the .dbpersondetails likewise binding.  There are 2 other dbperson details that I will bind in form, so I have kept @person in editform level.

Comment: Appears to be a known limitation on complex types. https://blazor-university.com/forms/handling-form-submission/

Comment: Thank you, based on your points and link, I got the cause and remedy too.  Fix is experimental to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation package.  Links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#validation-support  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/validation-in-blazor-app/